# Javascript not working in apache-served html

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I set up an apache server on gentoo, I want to be able to run javascript code in my html files served by apache.

If I manually open up the html file that lives on the apache server in Chrome, the javascript works fine. If I browse to the html file using the server address via apache, it does not execute. This is my test html, it's very simple:

```
<html>
    <h2>js test</h2>
    <script>
        alert("Hey");
    </script>
</html>
```

I haven't ever seen this behavior before. Any ideas?

EDIT:
What I mean by opening manually and using the server address is this:

```
file:///mnt/server/path/to/file.html (opening manually)
http://server/path/to/file.html (browsing to apache server)
```

EDIT 2:
No errors in apache's error_log. At first I was using jquery to try to do some ajax stuff, but I tried to simplify everything to the max for this question.

Comment: Well, you have no doctype, no head tag and no body tag. Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Your question is hard to decipher. What do you mean by _"manually open up the html file that lives on the apache server in Chrome"_, vs _"browse to the html file using the server address via apache"_? These are not explicit enough descriptions to understand exactly what you're doing.

Comment: That's not how JS in HTML works, HTML JS executes in your browser, if you just navigate to the HTML file server address nothing will happen. The running or not-running of JavaScript has __NOTHING__ to do with apache

Comment: Edited post to describe how I was accessing the html files

Comment: Is your Apache serving the right content type on those files? (Check in Chrome's Network tab)

Comment: An apache http server usually maps h t t p : / / server /  to a specific directory such as /var/www on the server.  Therefore the http path for a file is different from the file:// address for the same file.  And furthermore, by design, not every file can be served by the apache server, allowing most files to stay private unless they are in a directory (or subdirectory) configured for apache to use. Does that help?

Comment: Koterpillar, network tab reports text/html in both cases. Paul, Yes, the path to the file on the server is actually /var/www/localhost/htdocs... but I also have /var/www/localhost mapped via nfs to my desktop computer, so that was how I was getting the same file

Comment: OK.  Could it be that something in your browser blocks pop-ups, since alert() is a popup? alert() might behave differently in a file:// url vs an external url due to pop up allow/deny...

Comment: You can use "view source" in your browser to see if the javascript parts are being received...

Comment: You might add <head></head> and <body></body> tags around the appropriate sections to see if that matters, as well.

Comment: Paul, I decided to see if document.write() works, and it does. In my actual project, I use a header, footer and body php files to build up my html, I just added body tags and now all my jquery is working on apache-served files. Weird, since it isnt required when accessing the files directly, but thanks! Post a response and I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Blender, the HTML is missing the typical head.../head and body.../body sections.  Maybe this matters in the HTML loading properly and the browser triggering the script portions.

Also, pop ups like alert() can be blocked by pop up blockers in the browser that can differentiate a site vs a file url.